# Select random element from the list in Selenium Java and click on it, but getAttribute is not equal to zero

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get random element from the list and click on it. The thing is, the elements are products which have attribute "quantity" and I want to click on the random element which quantity is not equal to zero. I'm using Selenium and Java.

I tried to create two lists, one with all elements and the other to put elements which are not equals to zero and with Random class to click on element but to no avail, it does click on random element but sometimes hits the one with zero quantity.

```java
    List<WebElement> products= driver.findElements(By.id("elementId"));
    List<Integer> productsNotEqualToZero = new ArrayList<>();

    for(webElement:products){
    if(!webElement.getAttribute("quantity").equals("0")){

 
productsNotEqualToZero.add(Integer.ParseInt(webElement.getAttribute("quantity 
    ")))
    }
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int result = random.nextInt(productsNotEqualToZero.size());
    products.get(result).click;
```

The problem is that nothing guarantees that product attribute "quantity" is not equals to zero.

Comment: I would use xpath which just gets the items where attribute "quantity" is greater than zero.  That way you don't need two lists...  right now, though you are using an index which won't map properly.  result int is random from a subset of products than has a new index, not the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple approach.

**Sample HTML:**

```html
<html><head></head><body><div>
  <select>
   <option quantity="1">Apple</option>
   <option quantity="4">Banana</option>
   <option quantity="0">Cherry</option>
   <option quantity="1">DragonFruit</option>
  </select>
 </div><table border="1" id="mytable">
      
</table></body></html>
```

**Xpath:**

[image]

**Script:**

```
// get all products whose quanity >0
    List<WebElement> productElems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select/option[@quantity>'0']"));
    // get the len of productElems
    int maxProducts = productElems.size();
    // get random number
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomProduct = random.nextInt(maxProducts);
    // Select the list item
    productElems.get(randomProduct).click();
```